# Set X limits is not working in Seaborn plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a `dataframe` with `sex`, `age`, `weight` and `height`.

When I try to plot `sns.countplot` and limit the `xlim` to `62.0-68.0`, the plot is set to different limits - `57.6 to 58.2`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 5))
ax = sns.countplot(x='Weight', hue = 'Sex', data=guys)
ax.set_xlim(62.0, 68.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Since the count plot is counting the number of weights, I think you need to specify what index the weight you want to limit is on. In your example, that means the 62nd to 68th limit.

Comment: Without example data and without an explanation about what exactly you want to count, it is hard to provide a helpful answer.  Maybe you want a histogram? Something like `sns.histplot(x='Weight', bins=68 - 62 + 1, hue='Sex', data=guys[(guys['Weight'] >= 62) & (guys['Weight'] <= 68)], stat='count')` ?